# Twitter Data analyse with HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm very new in Hive and Hadoop and I want to create a very simple demo to analyse sample twitts like this:

T 2009-06-08 21:49:37
U http://twitter.com/blabla
W I think data mining is awesome!

T 2009-06-08 21:49:37
U http://twitter.com/blublu
W I don’t think so. I don’t like data mining
....
Generally is it possible to do that?
but I don't know exactly from which point should I strat.Do you know any simple and clear reference to do this job? or  would you please inform me (not in detail) what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell - you should create your own SerDe, which will present tweets in form of records and from there you can process tweets in hive as a table.
https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/developerguide.html#DeveloperGuide-SerDe